# Jquery scroll() function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, tinyscrollbar

here i have used tinyscrollbar for following code. so here i write scroll event for the tinyscrollbar but it is not working . can you help me ?

```
<div id="scrollbar1" class="scrollBox">
  <div class="scrollbar">
    <div class="track">
      <div class="thumb">
        <div class="end"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="viewport">
    <div class="overview">
    gula id tortor ornare luctus. Integer placerat urna non ligula sollicitudin vestibulum. Nunc vestibulum auctor massa, at varius nibh scelerisque eget. Aliquam convallis,
        </div>
              </div>
                </div>
```

Please see the example http://jsfiddle.net/rushijogle/7u377/7/

```
 $("#scrollbar1 .viewport").scroll(function(){

  alert("Scroller is scrolling :")

     });
```

The above function is not working ... thanx in adavcne :)

Comment: Why are you using tinyscrollbar in the first place? It works [without it](http://jsfiddle.net/7u377/11/). So the question is do you really need that plugin?

Comment: He included `jquery.tinyscrollbar.js` in HTML part instead like external content. Yeah he needs it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SEE THE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7u377/18/)**

JS Code -

```
$('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();

$("#scrollbar1").on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function() {
    onScroll();
});
$("#scrollbar1").on('mouseup', '.scrollbar', function(){
    onScroll();
});

function onScroll(){
    alert('Scrolling');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for more expected behaviour:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7u377/19/)

```
$('#scrollbar1').on('mousemove mouseup mousewheel DOMMouseScroll touchmove touchend', function (e) {
    if ($('body').is('.noSelect') || ((e.type === "mouseup" || e.type === "touchend") && $(e.target).closest('.scrollbar').length)) {
        console.log("Scroller is scrolling :");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the tinyscrollbar plugin is not actually "scrolling". In reality it is setting the position of the `.overview` container. So scrolling up by 30px will result in a css property like `style="top:-30px"`.

There is no scroll event registered.. because ther is none.
Unfortunately the plugin doesn't provide a callback so that it would tell you when it scrolls.

I created a workaround for you that tests if there has been a scroll action and calls a function. This gives you the same result no mater if the user scrolled by mousewheel, trackpad, arrow keys or by klicking on the scrollbar, and is not firing the event when the user only clicks on the scrollbar but doesnt actually scroll.

Heres the code:

```
$('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();

// onScroll test function
$.onScroll = function(scrollbar, callback){
    scrollbar = $(".overview", scrollbar);
    var top = scrollbar.css("top");

    setInterval(function(){
       var now = scrollbar.css("top");
       if(now !== top) callback();
       top=now;
    }, 100);   
}

// In use
$.onScroll($("#scrollbar1"), function(){
    console.log("Scroller is scrolling :")
})
```

And heres the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2gc6H/

Note that every scroll event is displayed in the console.